# If my MBA has 4 cores, why does About This Mac say it has 2?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, activity-monitor, intel

In About This Mac, it says that my Mac has a dual-core CPU, but Activity Monitor says that I have 4.

[image]

I also checked this in Terminal with `sysctl -n hw.ncpu` but it also gave 4. If I have 4 cores, why does About This Mac say I have a dual-core CPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two cores using [Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). That's an Intel idea that splits a core into two hypothetical cores, which allows for slightly more efficient multi-threading without any changes at the application-level.